# MySQL Select all clients that searched for two different items or more

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table like this :

```
serial,ip,term
1,1.2.3.4,bag
2,2.3.4.5,shampoo
3,1.2.3.4,handbag
4,3.4.5.6,clothes
5,2.3.4.5,battery
6,4.5.6.7,lamp
```

I want to select all IPs that did search for multiple different items while excluding the term 'bag' from the selection (in this case I am looking for 2.3.4.5)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ip 
FROM my_table
WHERE UPPER(term) NOT LIKE '%BAG%'
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(ip) > 1;
```

Normally I would recommend against using a function
in a search ([UPPER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_upper)), but since the wildcard is there,
the expression is [non-sargable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) in any case!

The db-fiddle is [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gg5yME5vnFscvhDCCaYK8w/2)!